# How to break long lines in vim?

Tags: vim, text-formatting

I have a quite big text file formed of blocks like

```
Short line.
Really long line.
Short line.
```

separated by empty lines, and I would like to use vim (on Linux) to break down the long lines and obtain blocks like

```
Short line.
This was
part of
a long line.
Short line.
```

My problem with `gq` (and `gw`) is that it reflows each block as an entire paragraph, i.e. it doesn't preserve the two line breaks within each block, and according to `:help fo-table` none of `gq`'s format options would allow me to do what I want.
I also thought that I could achieve my goal if I could define new-line characters to be paragraph delimiters, but according to `:help paragraph` those are hard-coded.

**Edit:** I know that I could use `gq` or `gw` to format each long line one by one, but since my file runs over a few thousand lines I am looking for a way to achieve this automatically.

Comment: By the way: I looked for solutions to my problem in vim's documentation, here on SU, and on the web, coming up empty. I will gladly delete this question if I overlooked something obvious.

Comment: There is [Can I justify text in Vim?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/509) at [vi.sx](http://vi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Glad to know there's a vi SE! Those answers don't address my issue, though, since I already knew about `gq` and `gw`. I'm also glad I didn't stop there, otherwise I wouldn't have learned about the `:g` command. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
:%norm! gww
```

This applies the `normal` command `gww` (which formats the current line as with `gw`) on the entire buffer, without taking customized mappings into account (to avoid problems if e.g. `gw` has been mapped to something else).

See

- `:help :%`
- `:help :norm`
- `:help gww`

This alternative is as per Ben's suggestion in the comments, and is more straightforward than the original solution, which is saved below since it might fit better in other similar circumstances due to the regular expression matching ability. In the "match all lines" case, it is unnecessarily brute, though.

---

Applying `gww` on every individual line in the buffer programmatically:

```
:g/^/norm gww
```

See `:help :g` and `:help norm`. `^` matches the beginning of a line, which in practice makes this match *every* line.

One can also opt to select only lines longer than e.g. 60 characters with

```
:g/\%>60v/norm gww
```

(see `:help \%<`) but in practice `gww` will only reformat lines longer than `textwidth` anyway, so it might not matter much in neither speed nor result.

(I am using `v` for "virtual column" instead of `c` for "column", since the latter really calculates a certain number of bytes into the line. This can lead to unexpected results when using multibyte encodings, which is often a reason to be wary. In practice it is not a real issue for the same reason as above, regarding that `gww` will not reformat lines shorter than `textwidth` anyway.)

Comment: Apparently `:g` fails without a pattern, so `:g//norm gww` doesn't work but `:g/.*/norm gww` does.

Comment: @A.P.: Huh, works for me. I am using Vim 7.4.488-6 from Debian Unstable.

Comment: `:g//` reuses the last search pattern; if there's none, it fails. Use `:g/^/` to apply to _all_ lines.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Ah, makes sense, since my last pattern during the tests was the line length aware one I demonstrated later. I will update the answer. Do you know where in the help this "empty pattern" behavior is mentioned? I can not trivially find it.

Comment: Looking through the manual, it is probably implied that the information given in `:help last-pattern` for normal searching applies to the `:global` command as well.

Comment: Even easier: `:%norm! gww`

Comment: @Ben: Indeed it is easier; I will add it as the primary solution. I originally thought of having to select lines of at least a certain length as in the `\%>60v` solution, until I quickly realized that `gww` was a no-op on "short" lines, making the line length selection unnecessary. Still using the regexp matching to match "anything" should have raised a warning flag regarding more straight-forward solutions :-) .

Answer (score 4):

Since you’ve already read the manual for the `gq` and `gw` commands, I figure you probably want something more convenient than manually moving to the long lines and then using `gw0`, `gw$` or another `gw` command to only format the current line.

I don’t know an easy way of breaking long lines in Vim over a block of text.
However, since you’ve mentioned that your using Vim on a GNU/Linux system, I’d suggest filtering your text through the GNU `fmt` command.

For the whole file:

```
:%!fmt --width=75 --split-only
```

For the current paragraph (using short options):

```
:'{,'}!fmt -75 -s
```

Explanation of the relevant `fmt` options are:

- `-w, --width=WIDTH` – maximum line width (default of 75 columns).
  The option `-WIDTH` is an abbreviated form of `--width=DIGITS` (if using this abbreviated version, it must be the first option).
- `-s, --split-only` – split long lines, but do not refill; this is the option that preserves your pre-existing hard line breaks.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `fmt`. I preferred to accept the other answer, though, because it requires only vim.

Comment: @A.P. No worries. It's a great answer and I'd have accepted it, myself. Both it and your question merit upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

From:

```
Short line.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Short line.
```

Putting the marker on the "lorem ipsum" line and pressing `gww` yields (with `textwidth=40` for clarity):

```
Short line.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Short line.
```

which to me seems like what you are asking for. If not, please feel free to clarify.

Comment: Yes but no, because you solution imply that he has to do that a lot of times going on all the "long lines"; that way the solution is on selection to `:norm gqq`

Answer (score 0):

I figure out this do the job:

```
:%s/\(\(\w\+\s\)\{1}\)/\r\1/g
```

Then, change 1 for your desired number of words to split.

Will produce:

```
Short line.

Really 
long line.

Short line.
```